# Search in content of selected lists (not one, not all, a few)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search

Is is possible (in SharePoint 2013 Foundation) to narrow search results to **a few** of selected lists?

The two things I was thinking about are:

- Modifying query parameters in osssearchresults.aspx page. But I've been able only to narrow search to **one** list using the `u` parameter.
- Creating some kind of Query in Basic Search Center but I don't really know how it works.